# Можно ли на github создать папку для нескольких репозиториев?

Tags: github

Можно ли на github создать папку для нескольких репозиториев?
Слышал об 'organization'. Мне собственно хочется создать папку '3dparty'.И кидать туда форки. Но поскольку при нажатии на 'fork' меня не спрашивают куда/где, думается что это не возможно.Но может в настройках аккаунта где-то есть?

Comment: При нажатии на fork спрашивает куда, если есть больше одного варианта

Comment: В организации у вас не будет папки, вы сможете добавлять форки так же как и в обычном аккаунте.

Answer (score 0):

Похоже что 'organization' действительно то что нужно. В правом верхнем углу(где значок аккаунта) кликаем на плюсик,выбираем 'New organization'.Даём название и имейл. Я назвал 3dparty и левый имейл.После создания, слева от списка репозиториев, появился список 'Organizations' и ссылка на 3dparty.Уже бросил в него пару форков. Но надо проверить настройки, поскольку настораживает адрес https://github.com/3dparty.

Выйдя из аккаунта, видно, что https://github.com/3dparty - действительно глобальный адрес, хоть просто так мембером и не стать.Нужен инвайт от владельца.

Но, как вы наверное заметили - это костыль.
Ну и вспоминается как зайдешь в репозитории гугл или буст - всё свалено в одну кучу)))
Странно как-то. Гитхаб известная контора и тут такое...)))Странно товарищи, странно)